# AWS Lambda and AWS SNS: Does it need a NAT Gateway?

Tags: aws-lambda, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns, aws-vpc

I am developing a React Native application for IOS and Android. I am using Django for my backend and aws rds for my database. It is deployed on AWS Lambda and both my lambdas and my rds are in a VPC. Everything worked well except for push notifications as they require my lambda functions to communicate to the public internet.

One way would be to create a NAT Gateway to allow that communication, but a NAT Gateway is quite costly.

I am thinking of another way which involves AWS Simple Notification Services (SNS). If I integrate that to my Django app, would the lambda functions be able to communicate with AWS SNS without requiring a NAT Gateway?

Comment: I am into the same problem, What did you find? Did you do we need nat in between

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to create an SNS service endpoint within the VPC your lambda function runs in:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-publishing-to-topics-from-vpc.html

Service endpoints are kind of like building a tunnel from your VPC to a specific service so it isn't considered the external Internet. You are billed for them but the price is a LOT cheaper than a NAT gateway, and if you're provisioning with CloudFormation tends to save a lot of complexity with building routes, etc.

https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/pricing/

Comment: Thank you! Although I am unsure if push notifications would still require me to communicate with the public internet to retrieve APNs or FCM tokens.